# Is there an official name for visual puzzles based on observation skill?

Tags: puzzle-identification

Is there a common/official name for visual puzzles that are based strictly on the observation skill - like the common "Where is Waldo" pictures, "find all faces", "count all X in the picture (or find a given number of them), "Spot a thief" and the likes - where the visual mess or tricky composition of the image obscures the location of the puzzle target?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the online realm, these are known as "hidden object/picture" games, and the definition also matches those which appear in books. [From Wikipedia (emph. not mine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle_video_game#Hidden_object_game):

> A **hidden object game** (sometimes called **hidden picture**) is a genre of puzzle video game in which the player must find items from a list that are hidden within a picture.

In essence, "Where's Waldo" is just a simpler version of this game, in which the list of items you are looking for has a length of one (though if I recall, there are sometimes more objects to find in Waldo).

Physical copies of these games also, I believe, can go by the same name.

Comment: Note that two-picture "spot the differences" would not be in this category by the given definition since there is not a list of target items.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: One could argue the list is there, but obscured. One picture is the list, the other is where you find elements different than on the list.